# How to create a Thread group inside a Thread group

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where I need to execute the http calls concurrently with a set of data (say 5 different data set).And then with same data set need to execute another set of https calls sequentially. And then with same data set need to execute another set of https calls concurrently again. These 3 cases I need to test with multiple iterations.

I tried with 3 separate thread groups. First one have number of threads 5 with Loop count 1. And the second one have number of threads 1 with Loop count 5. And the Third one have number of threads 5 with Loop count 1.

But this will not work when I need to execute the scenario for multiple iterations.

Answer (score 1):

As of current [JMeter version 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html) you cannot have nested Thread Groups.

If you need to mimic some form of [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests it can be done using [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) plugin.

The Parallel Controller plugin executes its children at exactly the same moment:

[image]

therefore it should be sufficient for fulfilling your requirement

[Parallel Sampler and Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampling-for-jmeter) can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

[image]